# Subsets of group which have regular intersection

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group, and $S,R$ be nonempty subsets of $G$. For which condition of $G,S,R$,
$$
|gS\cap R|=|S\cap R| \hbox{ for every } g\in G?\tag1
$$

Some partial results:

- If $S=G$ or $R=G$ then $S,R$ statisfies $(1)$.
- $|S\cap R||G|=\sum_{g\in G}|gS\cap R|=\sum_{s\in S,r\in R}|\{gs=r|g\in G\}|=|S||R|$
- $|G|$ divides $|S||R|$. So if $\gcd(|S|,|G|)=1$ then $R=G$ and if $G=C_p$ with $p$ is a prime number and either $R=G$ or $S=G$.
- Note that for $g_1,g_2\in G$, $g_1S,g_2R$ also statisfy $(1)$, so we can assume $e\in S\cap R$ and $|S\cap R|>0$.

New update: I've solved the case $S,R$ be the subgroups of $G$.

We have $|gS\cap R|=|S\cap R|\geq |\{e\}|>0, \forall g\in G$ so for each $g\in G$ there exist $s\in S,r\in R$ such that $g^{-1}s=r\Rightarrow g=sr^{-1}$. Therefore $G=\{sr|s\in S,r\in R\}$. We will prove that condition is enough.

If $S,R$ be the subgroups of $G$ and $G=\{sr|s\in S,r\in R\}$. Let $T=S\cap R$, $T$ is the subgroup of $S,R,G$. We see that if $h\in gS\cap R$ then $hT\in gS\cap R$ so $|gS\cap R|\geq |T|, \forall g\in G$, therefore $|S||R|=\sum_{g\in G}|gS\cap R|\geq |T||G|$.

Now consider the action of the group $S\times R$ on $G$ by $f_{s\times r}(g)=sgr^{-1}$. Because $G=\{sr|s\in S,r\in R\}$ so this action is transitive. The stabilizer of $e$ is $\{(t,t)|t\in T\}$, so by  orbit-stabilizer formula we have $|S||R|=|S\times R|=|Stab_e||G|=|T||G|$, this can only happen if and only if $|gS\cap R|=|T|=|S\cap R|, \forall g\in G$, so $S,R$ statisfy $(1)$.

Comment: Please say what you have tried. Just uploading a problem is not the right way.

Comment: thank you very much @DietrichBurde

Comment: Do you have an answer when $S$ and $R$ are subgroups? In that case $G = SR$.

Comment: @spin Thank for suggesting. Let me try.

Comment: @spin I've add it.

Comment: @VeronicaPhan: Seems right. In general is $|S \cap R| |G| = |S| |R|$ sufficient?

Comment: @spin Take $G=C_6$ (addition group of modulo $6$) and $S=\{0,1,2\},R=\{0,5\}$ then $|5S\cap R|=2$